# What is the time complexity of this nested for loop?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

What would be the time complexity be of these lines of code?

```
Begin
  sum = 0
  For i = 1 to n do
     For j = i to n do
       sum = sum + 1
End
```

I want to say O(n) = 2n^2 + 1 but I'm unsure because of the i=j part.

Comment: For `O()` you get rid of all non-leading polynomial terms (+1) and multiplicative constants (2*), so you're talking about `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Note that `2n^2 + 1 = O(n)` but not `O(n) = 2n^2 + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct!

A nested loop instinctively leads you to the right answer which is `O(n^2)`. In doing Big-O analysis, it usually doesn't matter being specific to the point i.e. saying the time complexity is `O(2n^2)` or `O(3n^2 + 1)` -- saying `O(n^2)` is enough since that is the dominating task of the function.

The i = j condition simply makes it so that there are...

1. i=1: `n` operations
2. i=2: `(n-1)` operations
3. ...
4. i=n: `1` operation

So, the sum of all operations you do is  `1 + 2 + ... n` = `n(n+1)/2` which is `O(n^2)`.